# Get final rendered html in Visual Studio 2017 without webview

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to get the finally rendered html from a webpage, not the view source, the actual final rendered html.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I have tried the WebView but is there not something like a library that will allow me to get the final rendered html without having to go through in this case the webview first? C# or VB.

Harry

Comment: You should take a look at webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I used this to achieve what you need, with a webview that is never reached (no method returning it, its purpose is only to renders the final html): https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/

I'm going to complete directly here as it is an external link if this is what you are looking for.